# ODK API : How to filter instanceIDs based on submission date

Tags: api, odk, instanceid, javarosa

I am transferring data from ODK to another application through API.

For this I am fetching the instances of an ODK form and then fetching each instance's details.

What I want is to filter the form Instances(InstanceID) based on submission date so that I don't have to loop through all of them.

Pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not Possible Yet.

Detail here : https://forum.opendatakit.org/t/filter-instanceids-based-on-submission-date/6789